# Trouble understanding of lowercase vs uppercase N in algorithms book?

Tags: algorithm

From Textbook: Consider a sequence, S, of n items whose keys are integers in the range [0, N − 1], for some integer N ≥ 2, and suppose that S should be sorted according to the keys of the items. In this case, it is possible to sort S in O(n + N) time.

Why is 1 being subtracted from the range? Is that the same as writing inclusive (0,N)?

Comment: No.  Same as `[0, N)` with real numbers.  But with integers it is `[0, N-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `[0, N-1]`, the values `0`, `1`, ... , `N-1` represent keys. Since the total count of these keys starting from `0` and ending at `N` would be *n + 1*, we subtract 1 to keep the count to *n*.

For second question, the parentheses imply exclusion. Square brackets imply inclusion. Therefore if you say `(0, N)`, then you exclude `0` and `N`, which is not same as `[0, N-1]`.

Comment: So is N the same as n which is the number of items?

Comment: @DanielKobe: No... _n_ is the total count of items. N has no relation with n. You could create these n items by taking 0, 2, 4, .... 2N - 2 instead of 0, 1, 2... N-1.

Comment: If N has no relation to n though then why would you minus one. Lets say there are 5 keys. N would equal 4 and n would equal 5 right? So N-1 would equal 3?

Comment: @DanielKobe: The relation is implicitly understood that with n and N, you want to match the count. But it ends there. Otw, why even bother with N & n and simply use just n everywhere. You can, as you are proposing, use N itself and explicitly state that N = n - 1.

Comment: So in this case though, N is the count of items, which is also n

Comment: @DanielKobe: The count of items is n only. The notation of N is for mapping the actual items. 0 is the first item, 1 is the second item... N-1 is the nth item.